# Replace special character with dash using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my `.htaccess` file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} company
RewriteRule ^company/(.*)$ details.php?company_name=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.php [L]
```

i have converted URL from,

```
www.myurl.com/detail.php?name-id
```

to

```
www.myurl.com/company/name-id
```

What i want is to **remove special character** (including # and +) from `/name-id` last part of url and **replace with dash**.

If anyone can help it wold be appreciable, Thank You in advance.

Comment: That should be happening where you generate those links, not in a rewrite rule.

Comment: Your `RewriteCond` directive is entirely superfluous. And your last `RewriteRule` looks like _nonsense_ - what is that supposed to be doing?

Comment: Thank You for suggestion @MrWhite , i have removed last line from .htaccess, and i'm rookie to url-rewriting that is why it's not proper.

Comment: @deceze I know sir, but is it possible to remove special character from url by .htaccess ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. (Note that `#` (unless it is URL encoded) will not appear in the URL that the _server_ sees anyway.)